# Explain System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",""); in layman terms

Tags: selenium-webdriver

Can some one please explain `System.setProperty("","");` in simple terms?

Comment: `System.setProperty("propertyName", "value");` - means exactly what it says. Set the system property `propertyName` to have the value `value`. If you need more information, try searching for it. There's a lot of information out there.

Comment: OP: Did you tried to read the docs? You would get better answers if you linked to the docs you found and asked for explanations. We are he not to find and read docs for you.

Answer (score 0):

Refer below answer.

> WebDriver uses native browser approach. Selenium offers inbuilt driver
>   for Firefox but not for other browsers. All drivers (Chrome Driver, IE
>   driver, etc.) are built based on the special JS Engine used by each
>   browser.

Selenium WebDriver works very well with Mozilla Firefox because it has a built in driver server. But the same is not true for Internet Explorer and Google Chrome. Firefox is the most traditional browser, thus Selenium WebDriver do not require any additional utility to be set before launching the browser. The Selenium package automatically references towards the default location of the firefox.exe, thus the user need not to set any other property.

If you ever get the “the path to the driver executable must be set by the webdriver. ie. driver system property” error or its similarly worded Chrome equivalent, it means that you need to install the driver servers on your browser. The driver server manages the calls between the browsers and the Selenium wire protocol.

The InternetExplorerDriver is a standalone server which implements WebDriver’s wire protocol

Similarly, Google Chrome doesn’t have a built-in server so you will need a Chrome driver server for communicating your Selenium code to the browser. You can download the Chrome driver server.

Founded from [here.](http://www.optimusinfo.com/selenium-webdriver-ie-chrome/)